# Scanning and connecting to wifi using Qt and wpa_supplicant.conf

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, wpa-supplicant, qt

I am writing a Qt based application on a ARM linux device. I want to be able to create wifi functionality in the most efficient way.
Currently I am using QProcess to run a script that modifies the network block of wpa_supplicant.conf and kicks off the wlan0 interface to connect to an access point. This is what the sh script looks like:

```
sed -i 's: ssid=.*: ssid="Name":' /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
sed -i 's: psk=.*: psk="Password":' /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
ifdown wlan0
ifup wlan0
```

And to scan networks I run a separate QProcess which runs the command:

```
iw wlan0 scan | grep SSID
```

I am new to Qt and embedded development so I want to ask a few questions. Is there a better way to run scripts from Qt other than using QProcess that's more efficient? How costly is using too many QProcesses?
I have also came across wpa_cli and I would like to use it but I don't know how to interface with it through Qt or any C++ application. If anyone could give me guidance to a better way of handling scanning and connecting to wifi (or in general the best way to run commands in linux from Qt) I would appreciate it.
Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the wpa_supplicant API (e.g. source code of `wpa_cli` or `wpa_gui`)), then you neither need to change `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`, nor do you need to run `iw wlan0 scan`.

Answer (score 1):

QProcess is by far the most direct method to run an external program. I use it frequently and parse the output of the command in linux.

Yes, there is another method to connect to networks directly using QNetwork which is easy also and not difficult

See this link for scanning networks using QT and QNetwork
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45486924/qt-scanning-wi-fi-by-qnetworkaccessmanager and this link
https://github.com/abdularis/Wifi-Client-Scanner and this one
https://github.com/nlharri/WifiScannerLinux

In case you need to connect to wpa supplicant, there is a nice program that shows you how to do it using qt
https://github.com/loh-tar/wpa-cute

to learn more about WPA Supplicant, please see this
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant

finally please give a thumb